# 404 media urls in Fire Bug

Tags: .htaccess, magento-1.9

I am getting lots of 404 errors in Fire Bug's Net tab. I have attached the screen shot to know more. The error gets continuously incremented in Fire Bug. I have checked for this and getting solutions for this but not related to this type of problem.
[image]

**Console Output**: 16(Keeps on incrementing, thereby slowing down the website) "NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://test.xxx.com/media/" /media/

Answer (score 0):

The /media/ path is not found, so it was returning 404 error.
You need to check from where it is calling.

Comment: Can you post console screenshot?

Comment: You have posted net tab screenshot, It will be better if you post console tab screenshot.

Comment: "http://test.xxx.com/media/" this is called from ajax script which not found.
Check where it called and simply comment out that.

Comment: How would I resolve this? means will I have to tweak htaccess file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96327/discussion-between-shailesh-daund-and-dushyant-joshi).